# If $ \sin^2 x=a $, what is the explicit form of $\sin(2x)$ in terms of $a$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

I am sorry if the question looks very simple, but I am asking if maybe there is an identity that I am unaware of. I have this equation

$$ \sin^2 x=a  $$
where $-\infty<x<\infty$ and $a>0$ are real parameters. By the given data, what is the value of $\sin(2x)$ in terms of $a$? Is there a way to express $\sin(2x)$ in terms of $\sin^2 x$ and $\cos^2 x$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ and $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$, you can write it as follows:
$$\sin(2x)=2\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}=2\sqrt{a(1-a)}.$$

Comment: Thanks; actually, I had doubts about considering  $\cos x=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$; I thought we should use both signs $\cos x=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$.  @csch2

Comment: For that you need to take into account in what region $x$ lies. For example, if $x$ is between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$, then $\sin(2x)$ will be negative and so the formula should take the negative sign.

Comment: A factor of $(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{2x}{\pi}\right\rfloor}$ would be needed.

Comment: Your formula always gives a nonnegative answer, which cannot be true for $\sin(2x)$.   See the answer by Jose Carlos Santos.

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be done. Note that $\sin^2\left(\frac\pi4\right)=\sin^2\left(-\frac\pi4\right)=\frac12$. But $\sin\left(2\times\frac\pi4\right)=1$, whereas $\sin\left(2\times\left(-\frac\pi4\right)\right)=-1$. Therefore, in general, $\sin(2x)$ cannot be computed from $\sin^2(x)$ alone.